# какой sql запрос быстрее CASE WHEN THEN или ELT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Подскажите, какой sql запрос быстрее будет выполняться - с использованием CASE WHEN THEN или с ELT?
Есть тяжёлый, даже очень запрос UPDATE ... SET `column`=SET WHEN ... THEN ELSE `column` END. Очень большой и выполняется крайне медленно.
Может с использованием ELT быстрее пойдёт?

Comment: Вряд ли. И использование case/elt наверняка это менее 0.01% времени всего запроса (если внутри какие нибудь фунции тяжелые не вызываются). Если он тяжелый - то либо долго ищет что обновить, либо обновляет слишком много. В первом случае надо оптимизировать с точки зрения быстрого поиска, во втором скорее всего ничего не поможет, кроме пересмотра вообще подхода при котором понадобилось такое обновление

Comment: @Mike. Внутри ничего тяжёлого, самое элементарное WHEN ... THEN, причём в  WHEN первичный ключ. А вот то, что обновляет слишком много - это да: примерно 10 тыс. строк из 300 тыс.

Comment: Сделайте select count() который посчитает те самые 10к записей которые сейчас подвергаются обновлению. Желательно просто с тем же самым where которое у update и сравните время. Думаю оно конечно гораздо меньше чем у update, но вопрос в том, сколько все таки времени занимает и нельзя ли хотя бы его сократить

Comment: @Mike а в чём смысл count()?

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется что в CASE WHEN лежат запросы и не маленькие. В таких случаях нужно смотреть на картину в целом и оптимизировать. А сам ELT по сути переход по индексу. Если Вам известно индексация то не думаю производительность сильно просядет на  CASE

Comment: Это одна беда, нужно смотреть также на дополнительные ньюансы типа триггеров и прочих

Comment: @Bigata потому что count() по времени работы будет наиболее близок к тому времени, которое update тратит на поиск. если делать select * то добавится еще время перетягивания записей на клиента

Comment: @Aziz Umarov не, никаких подзапросов, элементарное WHEN ... THEN

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы занимаетесь оптимизацией и вам интересен лишь данный участок, то проще всего заменить и сравнить результаты.

Но на вашем месте я пошел бы по другому пути.

1. Сколько записей задействовано в запросе.
2. Убрал бы вовсе CASE переходы и поставил бы какое нибудь константное значение.
3. Поставил рандомное значение. Значение возращяемое какой либо функцией.
4. Сократил бы количество переходов, да бы выяснить какой конкретно лочит либо загружает таблицу
5. Постоянно сравнивал бы результаты с эталонным Update

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в тяжести sql запроса. Каждый около 1МБ.